# RubyMine Change git version

Tags: git, github, rubymine

So I am having issues with git in RubyMine. When I try to clone from a repository for example: `git clone https://www.github.com/zai11/exampleRepo.git`; I get an error `error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version`.

From what I understand this happens because github dropped weak cryptography algorithms, causing older git clients to stop working (including mine which is v1.9.4).

As a workaround, I have tried installing an updated git client (v2.19.0) and using that. I went into File > Settings > Version Control > Git and set the path to executable field to `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe` and clicked apply, however after going into the terminal and running `git version` it still returns `git version 1.9.4.msysgit.2`

Comment: Are you sure that you're using the location of latest Git which you installed?  It sounds to me like you're just running the same older version.

Comment: @Tim Yes. The previous git installation was at `C:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd\git.exe` and as stated the new one was at `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe`. Also to make matters more confusing, when I clicked on the Test button a window popped up stating that `Git version is 2.19.0`

Comment: But when I get out of the Settings window and run `git version` it still returns `git version 1.9.4.mysysgit.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have unsinstalled Git first, and do a disk-wide search for any other git.exe.

You also, for testing, use and uncompress the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) portable archive [`PortableGit-2.19.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.19.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.19.0-64-bit.7z.exe) anywhere you want.

Then setup a simplified path in a CMD session.

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
set GIT_HOME=C:\Path\to\Git
set PATH=%GIT_HOME%;%GIT_HOME%\bin;%GIT_HOME%\usr\bin;%GIT_HOME%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

Add any other path you would need

Try again your command in that environment.